# Update field datetime to NOW() when chatter added to case

Tags: trigger, chatter, datetime, update

At present I am trying to use a workflow rule to update a field (Last Chatter Date/Time) which I have set to update whenever an update is added to a case.  At present chattering on a case doesn't seem to update my field.  Images below.   Did I set something up wrong here?

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the rule's intended entry criteria? All updates?

Comment: @JaredT Updates to chatter feed on the case.

Comment: @JaredT -- I added another image for the sake of clarity on what my intention is.

Answer (score 2):

Your workflow rule is applied to the `Case` object however the case object not what is being updated when you post to chatter. When a chatter post is made it creates a `Feed Item` object that is related to the case.

It is assuredly not enough to create a workflow rule on all feed items to meet your goal. You should carefully examine exactly what kind of posts/comments you want this rule to apply to, and to what type of records the posts must be related (in your instance, `Case`).

Here is a page out of the developer guide that goes into the spiderweb of Chatter and its objects:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_chatter.htm

This post is a little outdated but the second half should give you a solid idea of what you're working with:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_Chatter

Comment: is there any way to accomplish this without going into the rats nest of apex triggers and having to code ultra-specialized functions just to get the "last touch" on a case was made if the update was done via chatter?  This seems like an extremely convoluted workaround for something that is a really basic use case.

Comment: I'm sure someone with more experience using chatter could swoop in and explain, but it sounds to me like your use-case might be better suited using the `Case Comments` object, where things are quite a bit more suited for the direct relationship between the post and the case.

Comment: It doesn't look like the Feed Item has a correlation to the case comments object though, does it?

Comment: That's correct. I don't have much insight on your intended use for Chatter on cases but if you are tracking conversation for cases specifically the Case Comments object was built for internal discussion - Chatter is sort of a broader tool bolted onto most other objects.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my own question after MUCH fiddling and stumbling upon a largely related post:  https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-60993

So… It took me way longer than it should have, but here’s how I got this working:

1: Create a custom field (which I named “Last Chatter Feed Timestamp”) on the case object .

2: Go to setup -> create -> Workflow & approvals -> Process builder

3: New process, Name / Api / whatever doesn’t matter (I named mine “Chatter to update last modified field”)

4: “The process starts when” -> A record changes

5: Object: Feed Item

6: Criteria: Just execute the actions

7: Immediate Actions -> Record: [FeedItem].Parent ID (Case)

7a -> No criteria - Just update the records

7b. Field -> Last Chatter Feed Timestamp

7c. Type -> Formula

7d. Formula Value: NOW()

**Caveats**:  You will not be able to see the field unless you set it to being visible by your account type while setting up the custom field.  The field does not need to be added to any layouts, but does need to be visible (and preferably read only) to your account type.

Comment: I would test this solution thoroughly, especially with other types of chatter interactions and with other objects. Off the cuff, I would add a check to ensure the parent object is, in fact, a Case object.

Comment: It's worked so far for me -- though there's an annoying caveat where it is now working for comments made underneath top level feeditems... not sure how to get around that yet.

Comment: You may be able to whittle that down by filtering using the `FeedItem.Type` field: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_responses_feed_item.htm